# Save Numbers in File into a 2D Array

Tags: c#, arrays

i have some numbers in my file like this:

```
22 33 44 55
11 45 23 14
54 65 87 98
```

and i want to save them(after i split) in a two dimension array like:

```
x[0][1]==33
```

how can i do that??

edit:

i wrote some parts of it,i put comment in code:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\arash\Desktop\1.txt");
        string[] strr;
        List<List<int>> table = new List<List<int>>();
        List<int> row = new List<int>();
        string str;
        while ((str = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            strr = str.Split(' ');//here how should i save split output in two dimension array??

             }
```

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it can be like this:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\arash\Desktop\1.txt");
List<int[]> table = new List<int[]>();
string line;
string[] split;
int[] row;
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
    split = line.Split(' ');
    row = new int[split.Count];
    for (int x = 0; x < split.Count; x++) {
        row[x] = Convert.ToInt32(split[x]);
    }
    table.Add(row);
}
```

table can then be accessed like this:

```
table[y][x]
```

Answer (score 1):

By using nested loop you can easily create multidimensional array.

Nest two loops, the outer iterating over lines in the input, the inner over numbers in a line.

Or you can you Linq

```
var myArray = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\arash\Desktop\1.txt")
    .Where(s=> !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
    .Select(l => l.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

`myArray[0][1]` gives you 33